# Is it possible to show everyone tasks in shared calendar?

Tags: crm, vtiger

If I'm adding task through Calendar module (Calendar -> ListView -> add Task) then me and other users can see it in SharedCalendar, BUT I can't see tasks added through Project -> Tasks -> add Task in my SharedCalendar view. So, this is my question.

**Can I see tasks added from other modules in shared calendar?**

(my vtiger is 6.0.0)

Comment: Did you figure this one out, I am having the same problem?

Comment: @GerardvandenBosch No I didn't. :/ I'm not using vTiger anymore.